# Bitbucket deny push to one exact branch

Tags: git, bitbucket.org, push

Bitbucket deny push to one exact branch.I can do push to other branches, but not to dev branch. Nobody of my colegues know what is going on. Is there some specific settings for branches? I dont see any. This is what I get if I run git push in command line:

```
λ git push origin dev-k8s
To https://bitbucket.org/tomas-tiefenbach-simplaq/simplaq-portal.git
 ! [rejected]        dev-k8s -> dev-k8s (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/tomas-tiefenbach-simplaq/simplaq-portal.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And this is what I get from git pull

```
λ git pull origin dev-k8s
From https://bitbucket.org/tomas-tiefenbach-simplaq/simplaq-portal
 * branch            dev-k8s    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

This is what I get if I use -f force with push

```
λ git push -f origin dev-k8s
Enumerating objects: 11, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 570 bytes | 570.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Permission denied to update branch dev-k8s.
To https://bitbucket.org/tomas-tiefenbach-simplaq/simplaq-portal.git
 ! [remote rejected] dev-k8s -> dev-k8s (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/tomas-tiefenbach-simplaq/simplaq-portal.git'
```

This is result of gitk --all
[image]

Comment: The server seems to be configured to reject non-fast-forward commits. Does `gitk --all` show a non-linear history in the branch, i.e. a split and merge? You might need to `rebase` your changes.

Comment: That doesn't look like any special configuration – just a completely standard Git refusal to "roll back" a branch. Are you _sure_ that you have all the latest commits? Your commands don't show merging into the local dev-k8s branch. Take a look using `gitk --all` or `tig --all`.

Comment: I did run rebase. but did not help. Still the same. I tried use -f force with push. Result is in question edit.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I added result of gitk --all to question edit

Comment: @Bodo I added result of gitk --all to  question edit

Comment: Hmm, just in case, could you `git fetch` (without parameters) and _then_ check `gitk --all` again?

Comment: On a second thought, the problem already seems to be clear; the branch you're on is not actually the branch you're trying to push. Look at the commit labels in gitk's graph. (Since it probably shows too much irrelevant stuff, try `gitk dev-k8s dev-k8s-2 origin/dev-k8s` to trim the graph down.)

Comment: Please clarify in your question: Is `dev-k8s-2` the local branch you want to push into `remotes/origin/dev-k8s`?  You also have a local branch named `dev-k8s` which is obviously based on an older commit of `remotes/origin/dev-k8s`.

Comment: @Bodo dev-k8s-2 is test for sure that I have all remote changes. I created new branch from original to be sure I have all changes in local branch. But still the same result.

Comment: You haven't shown the result of pushing _this_ branch, though – you only show the result of pushing the "older" `dev-k8s`.

Comment: So I foud solution. My colleague change on Friday some settings of this branch and did not add me to the choosen one to make push.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in permissions for the branch.